# How to plot a heat map for a continuous 2D function in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

Suppose I have some continuous real function $f$ and $z = f(x, y)$. I want to plot a heat map to show how z varies as I change x and y in a certain range. I am unsure how to do this in a continuous way. The heat map function seems to be a disaster, reordering my inputs so the output is meaningless and although using plot.ly seems better, it still expects a matrix of values as the input. I was wondering whether there was a function or package more suited to what I need to do.